# string rotations

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[15];
    int i,j,n,*str;

    printf("Enter a string");
    scanf("%s",str);
    n=strlen(str);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        str[n]=str[0];

        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            str[j]=str[j+1];
        }
        str[n]='\0';
        printf("\n %s",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this program gives me all possible rotations of string

can anyone explain `str[n]=str[0]` and `str[j]=str[j+1]` meaning
instead of taking `n=strlen(s)` can we use `n=strlen(str)`
plz explain

Answer (score 3):

This rotates the string.  The way it does so is by moving the first character to the last place by doing `str[n] = str[0]` (`str[n]` is the string-terminating null character `'\0'`, then shifting the whole string down one (`str[j] = str[j+1]`), then replacing the null at the end (`str[n]='\0'`).

This code would, if it were using `s`, cause a buffer overrun if the string is longer than 14 characters.  However, there's also a logic error in the code: it should be either initializing `str` (as a `char*` not `int*`) or scanning into `s` with a length bound.  For instance:

`scanf("%14s", s);`

or

```
str = (char*)malloc(500);
scanf("%500s", str);
```

Comment: This code will generate a buffer overrun anyway, because str is not being initialized anywhere.

Comment: @adamk: True.  Edited to note.

Answer (score 0):

> instead of taking `n=strlen(s)` can we use `n=strlen(str)`

Actually, since str is an `int`-pointer that is not initialized anywhere, all uses of `str` should be replaced by `s` (it's probably just a typo).

Comment: Either it's a typo, or `str` was supposed to be declared as `char *str = s;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[15];
    char tmp_var;
    int i,j,n,*str;

    printf("Enter a string");
    scanf("%s",str);
    n=strlen(str);

    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        tmp_var  = str[i];
        str[i]   = str[n-i];
        str[n-i] = tmp_var;
    }
    printf("\n Rotated String is %s \n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation or comments in your answer to advise other viewers how it works.